# No puedo crear dist in grunt serve

Tags: angularjs, npm

desde ayer me tope con un problema que a la hora de compilar el proyecto con ayuda de `grunt serve:dist` me arroja un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probe diferentes maneras de solucionarlo como limipiar la cache de npm, borrar la carpeta `node_modules`, instalar con imagemin con npm y modificar las rutas en `Gruntfile.js` espicificando donde se encuentran los archivos.

Saludos

Comment: Coloca aqui el contenido de tu archivo `Gruntfile` y comenta con precisión que has intentado para que no hacer recomendaciones que ya probaste que no funcionaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo lanza la tarea imagemin, que es la encargada de comprimir las imágenes del proyecto.

¿Has añadido o eliminado alguna imagen últimamente?

En todo caso, revisa en el `Gruntfile` la configuración de imagemin para comprobar que la ruta donde guardas las imágenes así como los formatos que usas están incluidos.

Si usaste yeoman para generar el proyecto puedes utilizar las variables yeoman.app y yeoman.dist para definir las rutas, si no puedes poner las rutas a mano como 'dist/images'

```
imagemin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
      src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
},
```

`src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',` debería seleccionar todas las imágenes png, jpg, jpeg y gif del directorio images de tu app y guardarlas en dist/images.

Otra alternativa es recorrer todo el proyecto en busca de imágenes en lugar de colocarlas en la carpeta images con :

```
  cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
  src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}'],
```